# 'ner_ontonotes_bert_mult' model Custom train

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, deeppavlov

When I want to train this 'ner_ontonotes_bert_mult' model with my custom dataset it is showing the error below. (I have saved my datset in the `~\.deeppavlov\downloads\ontonotes`  folder that was mentioned in [deeppavlov documentation][1]. )

```
PS C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER> & c:/Users/sghanta/Desktop/NER/env/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(env) PS C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER> & c:/Users/sghanta/Desktop/NER/env/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/sghanta/Desktop/NER/train_model.py
C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.WCDJNK7YVMPZQ2ME2ZZHJJRJ3JIKNDB7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sghanta/Desktop/NER/train_model.py", line 12, in <module>
    ner_model = train_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\__init__.py", line 29, in train_model
    train_evaluate_model_from_config(config, download=download, recursive=recursive)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\commands\train.py", line 92, in train_evaluate_model_from_config
    data = read_data_by_config(config)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\commands\train.py", line 58, in read_data_by_config
    return reader.read(data_path, **reader_config)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\dataset_readers\conll2003_reader.py", line 56, in read
    dataset[name] = self.parse_ner_file(file_name)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\dataset_readers\conll2003_reader.py", line 106, in parse_ner_file
    raise Exception(f"Input is not valid {line}")
Exception: Input is not valid 
 O

(env) PS C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER>
```

After cleaning the dataset the above error has gone but this is the new error.
New Error

```
2021-08-12 02:43:35.335 ERROR in 'deeppavlov.core.common.params'['params'] at line 112: Exception in <class 'deeppavlov.models.bert.bert_sequence_tagger.BertSequenceTagger'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [13,13] rhs shape= [37,37]
         [[{{node save/Assign_76}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saver.py", line 1290, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [13,13] rhs shape= [37,37]
         [[node save/Assign_76 (defined at C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'save/Assign_76':
  File "c:/Users/sghanta/Desktop/NER/train_model.py", line 12, in <module>
    ner_model = train_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\__init__.py", line 29, in train_model
    train_evaluate_model_from_config(config, download=download, recursive=recursive)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\commands\train.py", line 121, in train_evaluate_model_from_config
    trainer.train(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\trainers\nn_trainer.py", line 334, in train
    self.fit_chainer(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\trainers\fit_trainer.py", line 104, in fit_chainer
    component = from_params(component_config, mode='train')
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\common\params.py", line 106, in from_params
    component = obj(**dict(config_params, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\models\tf_backend.py", line 76, in __call__
    obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\models\tf_backend.py", line 28, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\models\bert\bert_sequence_tagger.py", line 529, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\models\bert\bert_sequence_tagger.py", line 259, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\models\tf_backend.py", line 28, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\models\bert\bert_sequence_tagger.py", line 457, in load
    return super().load(exclude_scopes=exclude_scopes, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\models\tf_model.py", line 251, in load
    return super().load(exclude_scopes=exclude_scopes, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\deeppavlov\core\models\tf_model.py", line 54, in load
    saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saver.py", line 828, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saver.py", line 840, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saver.py", line 878, in _build
    build_restore=build_restore)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saver.py", line 508, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saver.py", line 350, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(saveable_tensors, shapes))
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py", line 73, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\state_ops.py", line 227, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_state_ops.py", line 66, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\sghanta\Desktop\NER\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Can anyone explain how to solve it.
[1]: http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html

Answer (score 0):

`conll2003_reader` dataset reader failed to parse the following line:

```
 O
```

`conll2003_reader` dataset reader expects that line is either empty or contains a token and a label. In your case only label is present.

So, I would suggest to clean your data from empty lines with labels.

Sample text from DeepPavlov [docs](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html#training-data):

```
EU B-ORG
rejects O
the O
call O
of O
Germany B-LOC
to O
boycott O
lamb O
from O
Great B-LOC
Britain I-LOC
. O

China B-LOC
```

Comment: I have changed it but it again giving this error:

Comment: Is number of labels in your dataset differ from Ontonotes data? It looks like you are trying to finetune the model that was trained on Ontonotes. To train the model from scratch (from BERT initialization) on your data change the model path (`NER_PATH` variable in the config) to make sure that nothing is re-used from Ontonotes model. The similar issue is discussed here: https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/issues/1044

Comment: I want to fine tune the model with some new tags. Is adding new tag showing the error?? And if the remove some tag from the ontonotes data then also it giving the error. Can you please help
@yurak.

Comment: Can you also told me how can I train the model from scratch

Comment: Yes, the last error from the question is caused by mismatch in the number of possible tags. If you want to use Ontonotes and your data together, that you have to merge datasets into one and re-train the model.

Comment: but I want to use some other tags also which is not present in ontonotes data. How to change the paths in config file?? @yurak

Comment: Just change `NER_PATH` variable and do not start downloading of pre-trained model `build_model(config, download=False`).